# How to achive such layout with recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have question if it is possible to achive such layout with recyclerview as I have drawn here: [image: layout]

On left side you can imagine a range of numbers and on the right side there are items, that match the range on the left side. For example first item on right starts at 0 and ends at 2.8. Is there any viable layout manager for this ? I tried going with grid but no outcome.

Comment: There is something called a `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`, sort of a Pinterest-looking layout, could you use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assign the indices shown here:

[image]

This could potentially be achieved with a `GridLayoutManager` with 3 columns. You will need to override `getSpanSize(int position)` and return 2 for positions that satisfy `position % 4 == 1` and return 1 otherwise.

This won't work exactly for the layout you have drawn there because the right hand cells are slightly different sizes and aren't exactly 3 times the height of the cells on the left. That said, this `GridLayoutManager` approach could set you on the right path.

Comment: already figured this out :) but thanks for your comment maybe it will help somebody else :) will mark this